# B2C Sign In - UI with dynamic content

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I am currently having issues with configuring my B2C AAD. I'd like to get [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-ui-customization-custom-dynamic) example up and running but I feel like that there are some points missing in the documentation.

I cloned the repository and would like to get the same code for my login process. I deployed it on a WebApp and I used the Identity Experience Framework to download the TrustFrameworkBase.xml and to edit the LoadUri accordingly ([Step 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-ui-customization-custom-dynamic#step-5-configure-your-content-definition)). I was also able to upload it without problems (Step 6).
The issue arises at Step 7 where it says to test the policy - The "Run Now" function is not available inside of the Identity Experience Framework. The other policies, outside of it, which I created, all have it.
I do not understand how I get to run this login procedure now.

I've set up MSAL for my frontend application and it uses a policy I created. The policy I created uses a custom login screen which I created using the template from another documentation. Do I have to point my frontend application to B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase now? Because that only ends up as the default screen.

Basically: How do I point my frontend application to my C# application for the login process?

Comment: Step 7 from the article asking to use Run Now from **B2C_1A_signup_signin** policy. Did you try from the same policy (relying party/ leaf policy)? Run now won't show for Base and Extension policies.  And to use Run Now, you must have at least one application created.

Comment: Is *B2C_1A_signup_signin* a policy I was supposed to create? Should it have a custom login screen or not? How does my C# application gets mapped to it? I'm major confiused sorry

Comment: Yes, Relying party policy is mandatory and you can also call this policy from C# application.  It is always good to get started with basic policies and try to integrate with C# application. There is a get start guide @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet-susi use and integrate with C# applicaiton. you can easily replace basic polices with advanced policies once you get fair idea.

Comment: If you want, you can also use custom UI using basic policies instead of advanced policies. There is a guide to integrate this @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization

Comment: for your comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50949932/b2c-sign-in-ui-with-dynamic-content?noredirect=1#comment88898698_50949932, you will see a custom login screen once you upload Relying party policy (in example it is **B2C_1A_signup_signin** )

Comment: Ok, so let me summarise this: Every policy I create is based upon the policies of the Identity Experience Framework and thus uses the URIs I set in the base configuration of it?

Comment: not exactly, but yes if you create multiple signup and sign in policies because all the signup and sign in policies use same content definition.  if you create edit profile or password reset policy then you need to use another content definition and update that load uri.